# ¿Por qué me sale el error "your php serv doesn't have mysql mod load"?

Tags: php

Cuando quiero conectar mi base de datos a Dreamweaver me sale un error al momento de hacer click en "seleccionar Base de datos" me sale el error:

> your php serv doesn't have mysql mod load

Comment: Podrías detallarnos más tu problema?

Answer (score 1):

Ve a tu php.ini y observe si el módulo para mysql está disponible.

Está en la parte que contiene líneas como estas:

```
;extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension=php_bz2.dll
...
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Revisa que `php_mysql.dll` esté descomentada

Como recomendación, quizá deberías usar mysqli o PDO para las conexiones. SI estás usando PHP7, ésto es obligatorio